# Can not mount the parted sdb1 to the directory

Tags: linux, centos, disk

I added a sdb disk, and there is a `sdb1` on it:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1              8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2              8:2    0 111.3G  0 part 
  ├─centos00-swap 253:0    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─centos00-root 253:1    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos00-home 253:2    0  53.5G  0 lvm  /home
sdb                 8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1              8:17   0 111.8G  0 part
```

I want to mount the sdb1 to /data, but I found I can not:

```
[root@localhost dev]# mount /dev/sdb1 /data
mount: unknow filesystem "LVM2_member"
```

this is the information I can provide:

```
[root@localhost dev]# fdisk -l

磁盘 /dev/sda：120.0 GB, 120034123776 字节，234441648 个扇区
Units = 扇区 of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
扇区大小(逻辑/物理)：512 字节 / 512 字节
I/O 大小(最小/最佳)：512 字节 / 512 字节
磁盘标签类型：dos
磁盘标识符：0x00026214

   设备 Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   234440703   116707328   8e  Linux LVM

磁盘 /dev/sdb：120.0 GB, 120034123776 字节，234441648 个扇区
Units = 扇区 of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
扇区大小(逻辑/物理)：512 字节 / 512 字节
I/O 大小(最小/最佳)：512 字节 / 512 字节
磁盘标签类型：dos
磁盘标识符：0x00085936

   设备 Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   234440703   117219328   8e  Linux LVM

磁盘 /dev/mapper/centos00-swap：8396 MB, 8396996608 字节，16400384 个扇区
Units = 扇区 of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
扇区大小(逻辑/物理)：512 字节 / 512 字节
I/O 大小(最小/最佳)：512 字节 / 512 字节


磁盘 /dev/mapper/centos00-root：53.7 GB, 53687091200 字节，104857600 个扇区
Units = 扇区 of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
扇区大小(逻辑/物理)：512 字节 / 512 字节
I/O 大小(最小/最佳)：512 字节 / 512 字节


磁盘 /dev/mapper/centos00-home：57.4 GB, 57420021760 字节，112148480 个扇区
Units = 扇区 of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
扇区大小(逻辑/物理)：512 字节 / 512 字节
I/O 大小(最小/最佳)：512 字节 / 512 字节
```

the `lvs`:

```
[root@localhost dev]# lvs
  WARNING: Device for PV Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F.
  LV   VG       Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home centos   -wi-----p- <164.82g                                                    
  root centos   -wi-----p-   50.00g                                                    
  swap centos   -wi-----p-    7.75g                                                    
  home centos00 -wi-ao----  <53.48g                                                    
  root centos00 -wi-ao----   50.00g                                                    
  swap centos00 -wi-ao----    7.82g
```

so, how can I mount my /dev/sdb1 to the /data?

---

the vgs shows:

```
[root@localhost dev]# vgs
  WARNING: Device for PV Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F.
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  centos     2   3   0 wz-pn-  222.57g 4.00m
  centos00   1   3   0 wz--n- <111.30g    0
```

the pvs shows:

```
[root@localhost dev]# pvs
  WARNING: Device for PV Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F.
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos00 lvm2 a--  <111.30g    0 
  /dev/sdb1  centos   lvm2 a--  <111.79g    0 
  [unknown]  centos   lvm2 a-m  <110.79g 4.00m
```

---

the lvscan shows bellow:

```
[root@localhost dev]# lvscan
  WARNING: Device for PV Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid Zov90S-LgGB-ScPG-Fxdx-3xD7-OkZv-Yi9s5F.
  inactive          '/dev/centos/swap' [7.75 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/centos/home' [<164.82 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/centos/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos00/swap' [7.82 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos00/home' [<53.48 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos00/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: Where did sdb1 come from?  Does it have any logical volumes?  What does lvscan say?

Comment: Looks like sdb1 is a PV like sda2. You can't mount it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `pvs` and `lvs` outputs, your `/dev/sdb1` is part of a LVM volume group named `centos` that is supposed to contain one more LVM physical volume (PV). The error message from the LVM commands includes the LVM uuid of the missing PV.

Because one of the PVs of that volume group is missing, the volume group cannot be activated automatically at boot time, nor with a regular `vgchange -ay centos` command.

Note that the size of the `home` logical volume (LV) of the `centos` volume group is reported to be bigger than the size of the PV. That means it spans at least two PVs.

My guess is that the `sdb` disk was the second disk in another system. That system probably originally had just a single disk, configured just like the `sda` disk on this system. But then its `/home` filesystem ran out of disk space, and someone added another disk and used it to extend `/home`. If that is true, then the missing disk would probably contain the entire `root` and `swap` LVs, and the beginning of `home` LV (of the `centos` volume group).

The `sdb1` LVM PV has a copy of LVM metadata of the `centos` volume group, so LVM now knows about all the LVs that belonged to the `centos` volume group. But only the tail end of the `home` LV is likely to be actually present on `sdb1`.

It is possible to use `lvchange -ay --activationmode partial --permission r /dev/mapper/centos-home` to activate the `home` LV of that volume group and make `/dev/mapper/centos-home` device available (in read-only mode, just to be safe!). But since that LV is not complete (the head end is missing!) you won't be able to mount it normally. After activating the LV in this way, you might be able to recover some files from it using data recovery tools like `photorec`.

It would be much better to get the missing disk also connected to this system: once both PVs of this volume group are present, all the LVs can be activated (either automatically at boot time, or using `vgchange -ay centos`) and mounted in the normal way. If the missing disk becomes `sdc` when plugged into this system, that is not a problem at all: LVM will figure it out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried from the GUI. Linux Distributions provide an application called 'Disks'.

Steps:

1. Open 'Disks' from your dock.
2. Select your disk name.
3. Click on Play button from right side(under the graph of that particular disk).

It will mount your disk automatically in **/media/root/** directory.
It will also shown in your file explorer's quick access sidebar.